# getting permission denied in docker run

Tags: docker, entry-point, docker-entrypoint

I am trying using Docker using Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile as follows, where I am using debian linux system.

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.7.1.3
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME /usr/local/airflow

..
..

COPY script/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY config/airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.cfg
..
..    
USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

So when I run  `docker build -t test .`, it build without problem.

However, when I run `docker run -p 8080:8080 test`.

It throws following error:

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/entrypoint.sh\": permission denied".
```

What is I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do this in the app repo: `chmod +x entrypoint.sh`

Comment: Robert's right. The `container_linux.go:247` error just refers to an error thrown from the container's ENTRYPOINT or CMD. In this case, a permissions issue.

Comment: You are right robert, Thanks..

Comment: I had a similar error because I tried to `docker run` a DIRECTORY (copy/paste mistake) instead of an executable FILE.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You need to change the permission of the bash file by `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` before calling ENTRYPOINT. So change your code to the following:

```
USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_HOME}
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Rebuild the image and run the container, it should work.

Comment: same issues, following this Google CLoud Platform tutorial  
  [https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker?  ]

I edited my code following your advice but still get the same permission denied error.   

    `FROM alpine
    COPY quickstart.sh /
    RUN chmod +x quickstart.sh
    CMD ["/quickstart.sh"]`

docker run gcr.io/autotagging-api/quickstart-image   

OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"/quickstart.sh\": permission denied": unknown.

I am  running docker desktop for windows

Comment: Adding the `RUN` doesn't appear to fix anything.  I had to apply it to the file locally to test that everything was working, but still blocked by why the permissions are not changed using `RUN`

Comment: Is there a reason why the `RUN` command wouldn't work? I'm still getting `unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/app/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown` after adding a `RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh` Basically, I had to use Dinei's answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483712/9888057)

Answer (score 17):

Since [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) copies files including their metadata, you can also simply change the permissions of the file in the host machine (the one building the Docker image):

```sh
$ chmod +x entrypoint.sh
```

Then, when running `docker build -t test .` the copied file will have the execution permission and `docker run -p 8080:8080 test` should work.

Obs.: I'm not advocating this as best practice, but still, it works.

Answer (score 7):

In your terminal, run "`chmod +x entrypoint.sh`"

or if the entrypoint.sh file is in a folder, run "`chmod +x folder_name/entrypoint.sh`"

Answer (score -2):

I changed the location of the entrypoint in the dockerfolder and rebuild & it worked!

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: sure, I replaced  the path in Dockerfile were it's /entrypoint to /user/local/entrypoint and rebuild the image.