# Permission denied while executing script entrypoint.sh from dockerfile in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, permission-denied

I have a **multistage** `dockerfile` which I'm deploying in k8s with script as `ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]`.

Deployment is done though helm and env is Azure.
While creating the container it errors out **"./entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown**

```
Warning  Failed     14s (x3 over 31s)  kubelet            Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused:
exec: "./entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
Warning  BackOff    1s (x4 over 30s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

I have given `chmod +x` to make it executable and `chmod 755` for permission.

**Dockerfile**

```
##############
##   Build   #
##############
FROM repo.azurecr.io/maven:3.8.1-jdk-11 AS BUILD
ARG WORKDIR=/opt/work

COPY . $WORKDIR/
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY ./settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2/repository \
    mvn clean package -pl app -am

RUN rm /root/.m2/settings.xml
RUN rm ./settings.xml

#################
###   Runtime   #
#################
FROM repo.azurecr.io/openjdk:11-jre-slim as RUNTIME
RUN mkdir /opt/app \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash javauser \
    && chown -R javauser:javauser /opt/app \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install curl -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=BUILD /opt/work/app/target/*.jar /opt/app/service.jar
COPY --from=BUILD /opt/work/entrypoint.sh /opt/app/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /opt/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /opt/app/entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /opt/app
USER javauser

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

PS: Please don't make it duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353378/2226710 as i have added `RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh` and it didn't solved the issue.

Comment: Try using bash (or your preferred shell if not bash) in the entrypoint, e.g. `ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh" ]`

Comment: Thanks @Blender Fox, it solved the issue. Meanwhile may i know what the difference between `ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]` && `ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh" ]` in terms of permission?

Comment: Also, can you please add the comment as a answer, so that i can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, have added

Comment: Does this work in plain Docker, without Kubernetes?  When you run the pod/container are you doing anything like mounting volumes that might hide the content in the image?

Comment: @DavidMaze pretty sure you can -- something similar like `docker run -it alpine bash -c /entrypoint.sh`

Comment: @DavidMaze sorry, my previous suggested comment wouldn't work, alpine doesn't have bash by standard. Instead, try something like `docker run -it debian bash -c ./entrypoint.sh`

Comment: Note that `bash -c ./entrypoint.sh` isn't substantially different from `./entrypoint.sh`.  It is different from `bash entrypoint.sh`, which forces using GNU bash even if the script isn't executable or its "shebang" line `#!...` names a different interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bash` (or your preferred shell if not `bash`) in the entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

This will run the entrypoint script even if you haven't set the script as executable (which I see you have)

You an also use this similarly with other scripts, for example with Python:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "./entrypoint.py" ]
```

You could also try calling the script with full executable path:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/app/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: how do you add arguments to the entrypoint, in the same string or add to list ?

Comment: IIRC, when using ENTRYPOINT, since that takes priority over CMD, when you run the container, it will use the ENTrYPOINT directive so to pass arguments to the ENTRYPOINT script, you would just do `docker run -it image-name arg1 arg2 arg3`