# Unable to start container process: permission denied: unknown

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am executing a `docker-compose up` in `WSL` for an image I have build and I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/my_path/my_shell_script": permission denied: unknown
```

I have found some suggestions in a couple of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687685/getting-permission-denied-in-docker-run) where they say to change the permission on the directory which I try to access but it didnt work, I still get the same error. Any idea how I can address this?

Comment: Maybe this could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882654/docker-entrypoint-running-bash-script-gets-permission-denied . You could assign execute permissions on your script during the image building

Comment: hello, thanks for the comment. Yes I found this as well also did not work.

Comment: `permission denied means permission denied` that was revealing really :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok it was a permissions problem, probably related to the user because when I simply changed the permissions just for the user to :

```
chmod u+x /my_path/my_shell_script
```

it did not work but when I did it for all users:

```
chmod a+x /my_path/my_shell_script
```

it solved the permission issue